# Как избавиться от бага при скролле с использованием swiper?

Tags: javascript, css, ios, iphone

## Описание бага:

При скролле появляется блик вверху или внизу (зависит от направления скролла) на несколько сотен миллисекунд чёрного цвета (как цвет body).

### Прослеженные зависимости:

1. Баг есть только на iPhone. Возможно, связано с iOS, а не только с
   телефоном.
2. Появление бага зависит от мощности, так как на более новых
       моделях его почти нет и он не так заметен. На старых он чаще и
       заметен сильнее.

### Дополнительная информация:

1. [Ссылка на видео с багом](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ryiuugc9a2appd8/IMG_2235.MOV?dl=0#) (лучше всего видно на 21 секунде и далее)
2. На сайте используется [swiper](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/#.VYksgPntlBc) слайдер
3. [Ссылка](http://neemble.ru/) на сайт